# How to align several different dataframes with different shapes on common column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a few different data frames like this below

```
df1
idx                   col1 col2  col3
2020-11-20 01:00:00   1    5     9
2020-11-20 02:00:00   2    6    10
2020-11-20 03:00:00   3    7    11
2020-11-20 04:00:00   4    8    12

df2
idx                   col4 col5  col6
2020-11-20 02:00:00   13   15   17
2020-11-20 03:00:00   14   16   18

df3
idx                   col7 col8  col9
2020-11-20 01:00:00   19   20    21
```

and essentially I need to keep all the columns from all DF's but align the values on the timestamp that is the index for each dataframe. My expected output is this

```
df_merged
idx                   col1 col2  col3  col4  col5   col6   col7   col8   col9
2020-11-20 01:00:00   1    5     9     NaN    NaN    NaN    19     20     21        
2020-11-20 02:00:00   2    6    10     13     15     17     NaN    NaN    NaN     
2020-11-20 03:00:00   3    7    11     14     16     18     NaN    NaN    NaN    
2020-11-20 04:00:00   4    8    12     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I have tried various things like merge, concat, join, manually doing it for hours now and I am stumped why it wont work. These df's are simplified versions, but my issue with these approaches are that my df1 has a length of 1619, df2 has a length of 1619, df3 has a length of 1617, and df4 (not here but follows same idea) has a length of 1613. When I try this

`df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='left'), [df1,df2,df3,df4])` what happens is that the `df_merged` size is now 12k rows (not 1619 like the original df). I tried dropping duplicates as well on the final `df_merged` and that only left me with like 600 rows. I also have tried manually combining them with `loc`, `iloc` and `isin()` but still no luck.

Really any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` with `how = 'outer'`.

Demonstration:

```
# data preparation
string = """idx    col1    col2    col3
2020-11-20 01:00:00    1    5     9
2020-11-20 02:00:00    2    6    10
2020-11-20 03:00:00    3    7    11
2020-11-20 04:00:00    4    8    12"""
data = [x.split('    ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])

string = """idx   col4   col5   col6
2020-11-20 02:00:00   13   15   17
2020-11-20 03:00:00   14   16   18"""
data = [x.split('   ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])

string = """idx   col7   col8   col9
2020-11-20 01:00:00   19   20    21"""
data = [x.split('   ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])

#solution
df.merge(df2, on = 'idx', how = 'outer').merge(df3, on='idx', how='outer')
```

Output:

```
idx col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9
0   2020-11-20 01:00:00 1   5   9   NaN NaN NaN 19  20  21
1   2020-11-20 02:00:00 2   6   10  13  15  17  NaN NaN NaN
2   2020-11-20 03:00:00 3   7   11  14  16  18  NaN NaN NaN
3   2020-11-20 04:00:00 4   8   12  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```